# Total ROWS selected in a LOOP ORACLE PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I just want to iterate from 0 to n-1 in a oracle loop, just like this:

```
FOR X IN CLEEVECTOR LOOP
```

But am I wonder if it is possible to use a conditional like:

```
    if X = TOTALROWS - 1 then 
       exit;
    END IF:
```

There is some recomendation, or solution ? 
Thank you for helping me out with this.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the question.  Is `cleevector` an integer variable?  Or are you trying to have a `FOR` loop that iterates through the results of a query but doesn't process the last row?

Comment: cleevector is a select statement I declared before. Actually, this is clvector:CURSOR CLEEVECTOR IS
 select regexp_substr(p_checkboxes,'[^,]+', 1, level) ID from dual
 connect by regexp_substr(p_checkboxes, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null;

Comment: But I got a problem with the cursor counter. I just need to break the loop when x = total -1

Comment: You can achieve it using where clause regexp_count(p_check_boxes,',') < LEVEL

Comment: If `p_checkboxes` is a string `A,B,C`, why would you always want to ignore the `C` element?  That's certainly possible to do.  But it doesn't seem to make a lot of sense-- it would seem to make much more sense not to put the `C` there in the first place or to explicitly filter that out in the `WHERE` clause of your query.

Comment: I dont want to ignore the last value, What was happening was the following: I got something like A,B,C + ANOTHER EXTRA VALUE . So when I tried to insert it into a table I got an error. One possible solution was commented bellow. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to process all but the last value returned by the cursor. Since a cursor doesn't know how many rows it will return you can't just say "Break if this is the second-to-last row". But you *can* save the value to be processed, then process it on the next iteration, as in

```
DECLARE
  strLast_ID  VARCHAR2(1000) := NULL;

  CURSOR CLEEVECTOR IS
    select regexp_substr(p_checkboxes,'[^,]+', 1, level) ID
      from dual
      connect by regexp_substr(p_checkboxes, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null;
BEGIN
  FOR X IN CLEEVECTOR LOOP
    IF strLast_ID IS NOT NULL THEN
      -- code to process strLast_ID
    END IF;

    strLast_ID := X.ID;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment this extensively to explain what's going on so Those Who Follow After will be able to figure out what the intent was.

Comment: Also, I must explain a little bit. My cursor reads an string separated by comma, but when I get the last position I didnt know how to validate for breaking the loop. Bob solution's said that I must save the last position returned by the cursor and validate it on the next iteration for avoiding the trouble